# Cannot manually upload a CSV or JSON to Kinvey

Tags: json, csv, kinvey

So I have a CSV file that I am trying to upload to a collection on the Kinvey console.
The problem is that it says that the upload is successful but nothing is shown in the table.
I have also tried converting my CSV file to a JSON object but same thing happened.
I made a sample table directly on Kinvey and downloaded the JSON Object of that table to compare to my own and it has no difference besides that it has the automatically added _id and two other attributes for dates and something else.
It would be incredibly efficient for me to add all of my data to Kinvey like this since I have a CSV file containing around 6700 stocks (rows) that each have about 30 different values (columns).

By the way, the csv file I am using is here:
http://finviz.com/export.ashx?v=151&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,39,40,41,59

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The columns names apparently cannot contain dots.